how can I use influxdb-python to collect data from an OPC UA server
Good day everyone I am a newbie here.
I have been able to use python to write data to influxdb.
How can I use influxdb-python to collect data from OPC-UA using influxdb-python client.
Any materials, link or examples will be appreciated.
I have tried to only write data into influxdb using python.
what I am expecting is a solution to help me send data from an OPC-UA server to influxdb using python.
